# Magento Backend without css and js?

Tags: magento2, admin, adminhtml

In Magento2, there were so many css and js files are missing after moving the site from local to live server. So I just deleted the pub/static/adminhtml folder. After that, adminhtml folder is not created yet. But in local, If I delete those folder, it is again regenerating. Why is it not happening in live server. Any permission problems? Please help here.

Comment: Yes, that seems Permission issue. You can refer to this : http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html

Comment: Changing permission did not help me.

Comment: Is there any problem with owner group. Because root user only can access to my project folder now.